# Align <Text> one below another in React Native view

Tags: react-native, styles

I'm trying to set 3  one below another inside my view. However, it is a mess as you can see in the image below.

[image]

My render method:

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const callIcon = 'https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/phone.png';

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={styles.pic} />
          <View>
            <View style={styles.nameContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.nameTxt}>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.end}>
              <Text style={styles.details}>Unit: {item.unitName}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.details}>{'\n'}Lease End Date: {item.leaseEndDate}</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sendEmail(item.tenantEmail)}>
                <Text style={styles.details}>Email: {item.tenantEmail}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.makeCall(item.tenantPhone)}>
            <Image style={[styles.icon, { marginRight: 50 }]} source={{ uri: callIcon }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }} >
        <FlatList
          extraData={this.state}
          data={this.state.calls}
          keyExtractor = { (item) => {
            return item.id;
          }}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And here are my styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: '#dcdcdc',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',

  },
  pic: {
    borderRadius: 25,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
  nameContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width: 270,
  },
  nameTxt: {
    marginLeft: 15,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: '#222',
    fontSize: 15,

  },
  mblTxt: {
    fontWeight: '200',
    color: '#777',
    fontSize: 13,
  },
  end: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  details: {
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: '#666',
    fontSize: 12,
    marginLeft: 15,
  },
  icon: {
    height: 28,
    width: 28,
  }
});
```

How can I fix the screen?

BTW... I'm use to bootstrap and frontend development, but I am new with react native, so if I am developing the screen wrong, please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `flexDirection` to `column` in `styles.end`. Since `alignItems` is `center`, they will all be centered, so you can remove that to align them all to the left.

```js
end: {
  flexDirection: 'column',
},
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't align left... Invalid prop 'alignItems of value 'left' supplied to 'StyleSheet end'

Comment: If you remove `alignItems` completely it will default `alignItems` to `flex-start`, which aligns everything to the left, or you can manually set `alignItems` to `flex-start`. The default value of `flexDirection` is `column` as well, so having `end` be an empty object would work just as well.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.